# Is it bad practice for me to include an "internal" package in my library?

Tags: java, shared-libraries

I am designing a library, and while I know that I should only make `public` the classes that I want the client to access, I am having trouble sticking to this best practice.  From what I understand, this is best practice.  I decided to put a package named `internal` inside one of the packages in my library to hold the classes that I intend to be package-private, but may end up as `public`.

The way packages work in Java seems flawed since you cant make a class "parent-package-private", so is there really a "bad practice" when it comes to issues like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait for Java 9, things will clear up. The new
module structure will allow restriction of public
classes anywhere outside the module.

But even till then, note that access isn't really enforceable. With the right usage of reflection you can access just anything, even private (not sure but I think Java 9's module will not give access through reflection).

Access modifiers are merely a note to the user "don't rely on me, I may change". If access modifiers are not possible, I'd consider it completely ok to give that note in some other way. Even the JDK has the `sun` and `com.sun` packages that are fully accessible but everybody knows that you shouldn't build code on them.

Looking in some popular APIs I find the package name `internal` quite often, so you're ok IMHO.

Comment: "With the right usage of reflection you can access just anything" -- only if you have no SecurityManager in place. Untrusted code cannot access "anything". Trusted code that you have yourself written or decided to run can of course do anything.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt   How should I let potential clients know not to use these classes?  Should I mark them somehow or just leave them as is in `internal`? @deprecated?  I guess if none of my methods are static one wouldn't really be able to use it, so this may not be necessary